# Uploading files to FTP Server with Codename One

Tags: ftp, upload, codenameone

I'm new to codename One and I would like to know if there is a way to upload files to my FTP Server.

What API can I use ?

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sockets but most people just use [multipart request](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/MultipartRequest.html) as it's more secure and easy to use than FTP.